# Does clustering of data in added variable plot merit transformation even without non-linearity?

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I'm running a regression and when examining the added-variable plot for one of my independent variables (DBLB), the data appears to be clustered to the left as below. 
[image]

A Box-Tidwell transformation is then performed. The results of the test are below.

```
 Score Statistic   p-value MLE of lambda
       -1.858855 0.0630477     0.2203419

iterations =  4
```

I'm not sure I'm interpreting the test right, but I think it's saying that at a 90% confidence level the independent variable should be transformed to the power of .2203419. The transformation is performed and the following added variable plot is produced.

[image]

Though the initial relationship does not appear to be non-linear, the transformation unclustered the partial regression plot and very slightly improved the overall significance of the model. Based on the evidence do I have cause to transform DBLB, do I not, or do I need to be looking at other criteria?

Comment: I would be inclined to take the results of Box-Tidwell (as with Box-Cox) as offering suggestions, not instructions. A power of .2203419 is to me (without further information) to be interpreted as suggesting logarithmic transformation, although naturally using that would require your data to be all positive. There is good physics for which a power of .25 would be entirely natural, but you don't say whether that is what you are doing.  From your cryptic variable names I would guess something financial.

Comment: With methods like this, and indeed more generally, two over-arching questions include: Is there a story behind a transformation that makes sense? How reproducible would I expect this result to be with other samples? (Even though you probably don't have other samples, the advice from experience would be: Not very reproducible at all.)

Comment: Your first plot suggests a few points with high leverage (influence). An alternative could be robust/resistant regression